# How to get all records which is nearest date from today?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have following data

```
SalId     EmpId   TakenSal  TakenDate       AvailSal        CompId
13        68       1000     02-Jul-2015     14000       1021
14        68       100      02-Jul-2015     13900       1021
15        69       1000     02-Jul-2015     11000       1021
16        82       1000     06-Jul-2015     9000        1024
17        82       1000     06-Jul-2015     8000        1024
18        83       1000     06-Jul-2015     9000        1024
19        83       1000     06-Jul-2015     8000        1024
20        82       1000     06-Jul-2015     7000        1024
21        82       1000     06-Jul-2015     6000        1024
22        82       1000     06-Jul-2015     5000        1024
23        82       1000     06-Jul-2015     4000        1024
24        94       1000     09-Jul-2015     9000        1014
25        94       1000     09-Jul-2015     8000        1014
26        94       1000     09-Jul-2015     7000        1014
27        94       1000     09-Jul-2015     6000        1014
```

in which I want to select those records 'TakenDate' nearest to today

I tried like below but throwing anerror

```
select *
from Employee_SalaryDetails
where Employee_SalaryDetails.TakenDate = max(TakenDate)
group by Employee_SalaryDetails.EmpId
having count(Employee_SalaryDetails.EmpId)>0
```

Comment: show error message and which dbms are you using?

Comment: Which means nearest records from today? Do you want to take all from the full day which is nearest to today?

Comment: yes..iam using sql server 2012

Comment: What is the desired result for the sample data you posted?

Comment: So you want to return the rows from 09-Jul-2015?

Comment: Can there be any future TakenDate's in your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for nearest date's data from today's date.

I have tried with your actual data,

```
CREATE TABLE AbbasTable
(
    SalId         INT
   ,EmpId         INT
   ,TakenSal      INT
   ,TakenDate     date
   ,AvailSal      INT
   ,CompId        INT
)

insert into AbbasTable values (13, 68,  1000 ,       '02-Jul-2015',     14000  ,     1021)
insert into AbbasTable values (14, 68,  100  ,'02-Jul-2015',    13900,     1021)
insert into AbbasTable values (15,69 ,1000   ,'02-Jul-2015',    11000,     1021)
insert into AbbasTable values (16,82 ,1000   ,'06-Jul-2015',    9000 ,     1024)
insert into AbbasTable values (17,82 ,1000   ,'06-Jul-2015',    8000 ,     1024)
insert into AbbasTable values (18,83 ,1000   ,'06-Jul-2015',    9000 ,     1024)
insert into AbbasTable values (19,83 ,1000   ,'06-Jul-2015',    8000 ,     1024)
insert into AbbasTable values (20,82 ,1000   ,'06-Jul-2015',    7000 ,     1024)
insert into AbbasTable values (21,82 ,1000   ,'06-Jul-2015',    6000 ,     1024)
insert into AbbasTable values (22,82 ,1000   ,'06-Jul-2015',    5000 ,     1024)
insert into AbbasTable values (23,82 ,1000   ,'06-Jul-2015',    4000 ,     1024)
insert into AbbasTable values (24,94 ,1000   ,'09-Jul-2015',    9000 ,     1014)
insert into AbbasTable values (25,94 ,1000   ,'09-Jul-2015',    8000 ,     1014)
insert into AbbasTable values (26,94 ,1000   ,'09-Jul-2015',    7000 ,     1014)
insert into AbbasTable values (27,94 ,1000   ,'09-Jul-2015',    6000 ,     1014)
```

For output use below query,

```
WITH FianlTable
AS
(
    SELECT AT.*
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY takendate DESC) AS RN
    FROM   AbbasTable AT
)
SELECT *
FROM   FianlTable
WHERE  RN = 1
ORDER BY
       TakenDate DESC
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0524f/2/0)

Comment: in this iam getting assending 'availsal' but I want desc 'availsal'..so how?

Comment: actually you want the result with data nearest to the today's date so I have used "ORDER BY TakenDate DESC" - but now if you want to get the result by **desc on availsal** then - Instead of "ORDER BY TakenDate DESC" - Use **ORDER BY AvailSal desc, TakenDate DESC** -- see this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0524f/3/0

Answer (score 0):

In the case there are no future dates in the table, simply return the most recent rows (i.e. "those records 'TakenDate' nearest to today"):

```
select *
from Employee_SalaryDetails
where TakenDate = (select max(TakenDate) from Employee_SalaryDetails)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want the nearest but below, you can use

```
select esd1.*
from Employee_SalaryDetails AS esd1
where 
  esd1.TakenDate <= getdate()
  and not exists (select 1 
                  from Employee_SalaryDetails AS esd2
                  where esd2.TakenDate <= getdate()
                     and esd2.TakenDate > esd1.TakenDate )
```